# C# : FTP How to identify 550 ftp error ,the Directory already exists or Directory not found

Tags: c#, directory, ftp-client

C# : FTP How to identify 550 ftp error ,the Directory already exists or Directory not found.
Because 550 is can be both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory already exists can only happen when you're trying to create a directory. So if you're creating a directory and you get a 550, then that's the one.

Directory not found can only happen while browsing to a directory. So again this is easily identifiable given what action you where doing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: you can't. Even if "directory already exists" can only happen when you are trying to create a directory, it may still return 550 for other reasons such as a missing or otherwise unaccessible parent directory.

The best you can do is to check for a return code of 550, and then check if the directory made it there by requesting its file listing. If it already exists, you'll get a listing, if not, you'll get an error.